# ingress can not get the default http backend

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

The ingress I config to run with the controller ingress-nginx.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - XXX.XX.com
    secretName: app-tls
  rules:
  - host: XXX.XX.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /my-api(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: app
          servicePort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-api
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-api
  ports:
  - name: app
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
```

I can run the api locally `curl localIP:3000/testapi`, but it can not run remotely.

```
# kubectl describe ingress app-ingress
Name:             app-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          XX.XX.XX.XX
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
TLS:
  app-tls terminates www.daichenchen.cn
Rules:
  Host                Path  Backends
  ----                ----  --------
  XXX.XX.com
                      /my-api(/|$)(.*)   app:80 (<error: endpoints "app" not found>)
```

I already succeed install the ingress-nginx and all the pod work without error.

Comment: have you deployed the default-http-backend service and configured on ingress controller?

Comment: This default-http-backend seems the default configuration in ingress, I have not config it.

Comment: The traffic is sent to the default-backend if the ingress config does not match any host in its configuration(which seems to be the case here, because in the ingress the `serviceName` is looking for `app`, but your service is named  `my-api`). Are you trying to fix this, or are you trying to figure out why the default backend is not working as you'd expect?

Comment: I'm working to check out why the ingress cannot find the app service. I using the daemonset ingress-nginx to run in master, I think I will try to use another type nodePort to work it out.

Answer (score 9):

Your defined `serviceName` in `Ingress` rules and `Service` should be same.

Like this :

```yaml
...
  rules:
  - host: XXX.XX.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /my-api(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: app
          servicePort: 80
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-api
  ports:
  - name: app
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
```

If `Ingress` and the `Service` is in different namespace, you can also add the service name to the ingress rule. In this case you need to use dns name for service `<service-name>.<namespace>`.

For example:

```yaml
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /my-api
        backend:
          serviceName: test-service.test-namespace
          servicePort: 80
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-service
  namespace: test-namespace
```

Answer (score 4):

The way ingress controller finds out `Endpoints` of a service is it searches for a kubernetes service with the `serviceName` provided in the ingress resource in the namespace where you have created the ingress resource. If there is no kubernetes service with `serviceName` found you get `endpoints not found`.

The `Endpoints` of the service contains the IPs of pods behind the kubernetes service.

So in your case either the kubernetes service does not exist or it's in a different namespace than where ingress resource is created.

Some variant of [nginx](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress) ingress controller does not support default backend and for this it's expected to have the `error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found`

Another variant of [nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) ingress controller supports default backend.

Double check which variant of nginx ingress controller you installed

Comment: I install the support default backend one, but why it report the `error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found` error.